# Accessing $_REQUEST from an indirect call to a PHP script

Tags: php, post, get, request

I want to access $_REQUEST within a PHP script that generates a JavaScript file. Here is my barebones index.php page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="phpGeneratedScript.js.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my barebones .js.php file:

```
<?php echo "alert('".json_encode($_REQUEST)."')"; ?>
```

When I visit `index.php?key=value`, I see a query displayed in the page, but not in the alert. Is there a way to access $_REQUEST (or $_GET or $_POST) from within a PHP script that is not directly `include`d?

EDIT: To partially answer my own question - this adds the query string to the call to the php file that returns the JavaScript file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <?php
  $query = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
  echo
  "<script src='phpGeneratedScript.js.php?$query'></script>"
  ?>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST); ?>
</body>
</html.
```

However, this does not handle an POST data which may be sent with the original request.

Following drew010's suggestions, I tried this:

`html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <?php
  $query = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
  echo
  "<script src='phpGeneratedScript.js.php?$query'></script>"
  ?>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    if (!$_POST) { ?>
      <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <!--input type="text" name="name" value="value"--><br>
        <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Submit'>
      </form>
 <? } else {
      echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
      echo "<br />";
      echo json_encode($_POST);
    }
  ?>
</body>
```

`js.php`

```
<?php
echo "console.log('".json_encode($_REQUEST)."');";
echo "console.log('".json_encode($_POST)."')";
?>
```

Here is the output in the browser window, after I click on the Submit button:

```
{"submit":"Submit","PHPSESSID":"b6eb4d1d73fc75976a16031003f58fa0"}
{"submit":"Submit"}
```

Both $_REQUEST and $_POST are correctly populated.

Here is the output in the console:

```
{"submit":"Submit","PHPSESSID":"b6eb4d1d73fc75976a16031003f58fa0"}
[]
```

The $_POST data has been added to the $_REQUEST data, but it is not visible in $_POST. Is this what you would expect, or is there a way to adjust my scripts to show $_POST data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$query = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
echo "<script src='phpGeneratedScript.js.php?$query'></script>";
```

Try:

```
$query = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
```

`parse_url()` with `PHP_URL_QUERY` will only return GET data from the query string.

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) will create a URL-encoded string from both GET and POST data.